# iOS Rich push notification not showing image in some devices

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

We have a push notification with image, and the problem we are facing is that in some device the image is not shown.

Specifics are: In iPhone 8 running on iOS 11.4.1 just the text of push is shown no image.
Same notification in iPhone X running on 12.1 is working properly and showing the image.

Any ideas on what might cause this?

Answer (score 9):

To support images in push notifications a `Notification Extension` is required.

This Extension has it's own Deployment Target. Perhaps the target for it is defined as iOS 12 which is why it does not work on versions lower than that.

Please check Deployment Info under the General tab for you Notification Extension target.

Comment: Didn't realize we needed to do this! Explains the problem quite well. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem here. Target is correctly setup, but I recently discovered that image not being displayed in my iPhone 11, but in iPhone 8 it works perfectly. Any idea on what is wrong with this?

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto have you found any solution?

Comment: I did. After debugging the notification service, i found that the service is not running. Then I restart my iPhone then everything works correctly.

Comment: after restarted its working fine from my end also

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup notification exension for receiving notification image in iOS.

This might help - https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2432#issuecomment-520196672