# firebase-admin SDK changes key name from image to image_url on iOS

Tags: ios, node.js, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am using firebase SDK to send push notification to iOS app users

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./firebase-adminSDK.json");
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});
 
        const notif = {
            data: {
                title : "hello",
                body:"hello",
            },
            notification : {
                title : "title to iOS",
                body:"Message to iOS",
            },
            apns: {
                payload: {
                    aps: {
                        mutableContent: 1
                    }
                },
                fcmOptions: {
                    image: "https://example.com/image.png"
                }
            },
            tokens: [],
        };


//looped over some list and pushed fcm tokens on to `tokens` array


await messaging.sendMulticast(notif)
```

But when ios device gets it the key name for `image` changes to `image_url` which is not expected since iOS need key name as `image` only. How do I stop sdk from changing the key name?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53294578/ios-rich-push-notification-not-showing-image-in-some-devices